# about Square Register App Url Scheme Parameter

Tags: ios, square

Can I pass parameters of quantity and unit price and brand name to square register app,using url scheme?

Comment: Square? Which Square?

Comment: @Raptor Presumably Square.com, which offers a product called Square Register.

Comment: Have you checked with Square?

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, it is checked.I'm sure the URL scheme of the following three.

square-register:
square-register-terminal:
square-commerce-v1:

I want to know the parameters that can be added to this URL scheme.